# Does IBM Database Add-Ins for Visual Studio support VS2019?

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio, webforms, db2, visual-studio-2019

After scouting numerous articles and stack overflow for hours it seems that the IBM Database Add-Ins are not supported for Visual Studio 2019. Do correct me if I'm wrong.

Reasons for installing the Add Ins was to create entity classes in asp.net using web forms.

IBM Database Version : DB2 LUW 10.5

Reasons for the conclusions:

1. Installed the same fix packs for the  IBM Data Server Driver Package as well as IBM Database Add-Ins for Visual Studio (Fix Pack 11) https://www.ibm.com/support/pages/node/3501195
2. Log Error Message : **MSI (c) (98:58) [17:45:41:129]: Windows Installer installed the product. Product Name: IBM Database Add-Ins for Visual Studio, Product Version: 10.5.1100.2866, Product Language: 1041, Manufacturer: Company Name, Installation Success or Error Status: 1603**

If the add in does not support Visual Studio 2019 , what would be the best replacement for Entity Framework 6.0 in order to use with IBM Db2? 
If the add in does support Visual Studio 2019 is there a workaround to the following problem?

Comment: Here is the link to the page that shows Db2 v11.5 supports Visual Studio 2019. https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEPGG_11.5.0/com.ibm.swg.vs.addins.doc/html/ibmdevori-DevAddInSystemRequirements.htm

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get paid support (from IBM) for Visual-Studio 2019 in Db2, you need to have the  visual studio add in that comes with Db2 v11.5.

For Db2 V10.5, it supports up to Visual Studio 2013.

It does not mean it will not work with older Db2 versions, but when you have issues (which is very likely), you won't get much help from IBM unless you have the right versions. You might be able to devise workarounds in some cases, but why bother?

If you are paying for a licence for Db2, pay for the current version and get the relevant paid support included.   If you are not paying (for example, you are using a community edition) then get the latest version anyway. There seems no genuine reason for using the (out of support) Db2 v10.5 build if you are trying to use it with Microsoft software that was developed long after Db2 v10.5 was created.

Here is the link to the page that shows Db2 v11.5 supports Visual Studio 2019. 
https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEPGG_11.5.0/com.ibm.swg.vs.addins.doc/html/ibmdevtsk-MigratingDB2Projects.htm

Comment: that you. I checked the links you sent and it seems there is no support for DB 10.5 with Visual Studio 2019. Unfortunately the circumstances are such where i will not be able to upgrade to DBv11.5.